Halo Mega Bloks set identification. Pics included
Short version, bought a gunpla kit at a flee market and there were bags of megabloks stuff in there as well. I believe they came from a Halo set based on the included figure. Included are some pictures of 2 of the bags. Last picture is the second bag flipped over to show more of the contents. Seems to have 3 smaller bags in it. There were a few more bags I can post pictures of if needed or empty one to show its contents
First bag was labeled x1033a and the second's outer bag is xstd975431




Hi lexcia and welcome to Bricks.SE! If you have any more pictures, please attach them as well, especially since Mega Bloks products are not nearly as well documented and catalogized as LEGO sets. The two bags we can now see all have quite generic pieces too, and I can't spot the figure you mentioned, but which would be helpful for the identification. After having done so, please take the [tour] and check out the [help] pages to learn more about how this site and the community functions and what are the expectations and rules. Play well!

Got it Zovits. Off to work right now so I'll add more tonight after work.
